# How to create a function by passing a column name as an argument without specifying data each time?

Tags: r

I have two issues:

1. I want to create a function by passing a column name (I'm getting this error: `` Error in `$.default`(dat, "var") : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors ``)
2. Then, I would like to create a function without having to specify the data each time (I tried using `attach(dat)` but it didn't work)

I'm trying to create a function that lets an user input a dataset and a column name.

Here's the function I'm trying to create'

```
fre <- function(dat, var) {
      
            abc <- questionr::na.rm(dat$var)
            abc <- questionr::freq(abc)
            abc <- cbind(Label = rownames(abc), abc)
            abc <- questionr::rename.variable(abc, "n", "Frequency")
            abc <- questionr::rename.variable(abc, "%", "Percent")
            abc <- tidyr::separate(abc, Label, into = c("Value", "Label"), sep = "] ")
            row.names(abc) <- NULL
            abc <- abc %>% dplyr::mutate(Value = gsub("[[:punct:]]", '', Value)) %>% dplyr::select(Label, Value, Frequency, Percent)
            abc
}
```

Reproducible example

```
library(haven)
#install.packages("questionr")
library(questionr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Load data
dat <- read_sav(url("http://staff.bath.ac.uk/pssiw/stats2/SAQ.sav"))


abc <- questionr::na.rm(dat$Q01)
abc <- questionr::freq(abc)
abc <- cbind(Label = rownames(abc), abc)
abc <- questionr::rename.variable(abc, "n", "Frequency")
abc <- questionr::rename.variable(abc, "%", "Percent")
abc <- tidyr::separate(abc, Label, into = c("Value", "Label"), sep = "] ")
row.names(abc) <- NULL
abc <- abc %>% dplyr::mutate(Value = gsub("[[:punct:]]", '', Value)) %>% dplyr::select(Label, Value, Frequency, Percent)
abc
```

In the end, my output from the above code looks like this:
[image]

I'm trying to get this by using this function:

```
fre(dat, Q01)
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Error in `$.default`(dat, "var") : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

How should I pass the column name in this function for it to work?
I tried `var <- enquo(var)` but it didn't work.

For the second issue, I've tried using `attach(dat)` before calling a function, but it didn't work. Ideally, I would like to make the `fre` function work and then eventually use it without passing the data argument.

Comment: `dat[[var]]`, not `dat$var`. (For this, see https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Indexing)

Comment: `var` needs to be a *string*, not a symbol. If you are accustomed to the tidyverse way of *not quoting variable names*, then ... writing functions to that is harder. Either `fre(dat, "Q01")` or read and master https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need too much black magic here. I've made 2 versions of the function.

- `fre_pipe` needs the data as an input argument, but it can be used with the pipe
- `fre_free` relies on an object called `global_dat`that has to be defined in the calling environment

You don't need `enquo` here, because you don't need to capture the environment of your variable. `ensym` is enough (it ensures that your `var` is treated as a symbol and is not executed). In the second step, you can use `as_string` to convert it to a string. For further reading see the [metaprogramming chapter](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html) in advanced R.

```r
library(haven)
library(questionr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Load data
dat <- read_sav(url("http://staff.bath.ac.uk/pssiw/stats2/SAQ.sav"))

fre_pipe <- function(.data, var) {
  var <- rlang::ensym(var)
  
  abc <- questionr::na.rm(.data[, rlang::as_string(var)])
  abc <- questionr::freq(abc)
  abc <- cbind(Label = rownames(abc), abc)
  abc <- questionr::rename.variable(abc, "n", "Frequency")
  abc <- questionr::rename.variable(abc, "%", "Percent")
  abc <- tidyr::separate(abc, Label, into = c("Value", "Label"), sep = "] ")
  row.names(abc) <- NULL
  abc <- abc %>% dplyr::mutate(Value = gsub("[[:punct:]]", '', Value)) %>% dplyr::select(Label, Value, Frequency, Percent)
  abc
}

dat %>% fre_pipe(Q01)
#>               Label Value Frequency Percent
#> 1    Strongly agree     1       270    10.5
#> 2             Agree     2      1338    52.0
#> 3           Neither     3       735    28.6
#> 4          Disagree     4       187     7.3
#> 5 Strongly disagree     5        41     1.6
#> 6      Not answered     9         0     0.0

fre_free <- function(var) {
  var <- rlang::ensym(var)
  
  abc <- questionr::na.rm(global_dat[, rlang::as_string(var)])
  abc <- questionr::freq(abc)
  abc <- cbind(Label = rownames(abc), abc)
  abc <- questionr::rename.variable(abc, "n", "Frequency")
  abc <- questionr::rename.variable(abc, "%", "Percent")
  abc <- tidyr::separate(abc, Label, into = c("Value", "Label"), sep = "] ")
  row.names(abc) <- NULL
  abc <- abc %>% dplyr::mutate(Value = gsub("[[:punct:]]", '', Value)) %>% dplyr::select(Label, Value, Frequency, Percent)
  abc
}

global_dat <- dat

fre_free(Q01)
#>               Label Value Frequency Percent
#> 1    Strongly agree     1       270    10.5
#> 2             Agree     2      1338    52.0
#> 3           Neither     3       735    28.6
#> 4          Disagree     4       187     7.3
#> 5 Strongly disagree     5        41     1.6
#> 6      Not answered     9         0     0.0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I don't think that `fre_free` without the data argument is good style. If you're tired of always repeating the argument, maybe you want to apply your function repeatedly with `lapply` or `map`? Something like:

```r
vector_with_column_names %>% 
  purrr::walk(~print(fre(dat = dat, var = .x)))
```

(But here the normal `c(Q01, Q02)` would not work and you would either need to make a function to create vectors of symbols or use the column names.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on r2evans comments, this worked :

```
fre <- function(dat, var) {
            abc <- questionr::na.rm(dat[[var]])
            abc <- questionr::freq(abc)
            abc <- cbind(Label = rownames(abc), abc)
            abc <- questionr::rename.variable(abc, "n", "Frequency")
            abc <- questionr::rename.variable(abc, "%", "Percent")
            abc <- tidyr::separate(abc, Label, into = c("Value", "Label"), sep = "] ")
            row.names(abc) <- NULL
            abc <- abc %>% dplyr::mutate(Value = gsub("[[:punct:]]", '', Value)) %>% dplyr::select(Label, Value, Frequency, Percent)
            abc
}

fre(dat, "Q01")
```

But, I'm still looking for a way to not pass the data argument each time. And it would be a bonus to find a way to not use `""`.